# Typedef's and nodes

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

This code is supposed to build a simple linked list containing integers from 0 to 20. I keep getting the error: `unknown type name 'node'` when I compile my code for what seems every instance of node in the program. I'm not sure if I have to define them or there is a bigger flaw in the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()  {
    int i;
    struct node *first=NULL;
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
        first=insertrear(first,i);
    dispnodes(first);
    sum(first);

return 0;
}
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

 node* getnode(node *temp,int i) {
    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data=i;
    temp->link=NULL;
    return temp;
}
node* insertrear(node *first,int a) {
    node *temp=NULL,*i;
    temp= getnode(temp,a);
    if(first==NULL) {
        first=temp;
        return first;
    }

    for(i=first;i->link!=NULL;i=i->link);
        i->link=temp;
        return first;
}

void dispnodes(node *first) {
    int j;
    if(first==NULL) {
        printf("\nlist empty");
        return;
    }
    node *i;
    for(i=first,j=0;i!=NULL;j++,i=i->link)
        printf("\nNode #%d contains %d  ",j,i->data);
}

void sum(node *first)   {
    node *i;
    int total=0;
    for(i=first;i!=NULL;i=i->link)
        total+=i->data;
    printf("\nThe sum total of all nodes in this list is %d",total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify a label for the typedef struct node or not typedef the struct node.

The way you are using it, you can do following.

```
/* Forward declare typedef _node to node */
typedef struct node_ node;

/* Define struct node_ */
struct node_ {
    int data;
    node *link;
};
```

You should have the forward declaration above your `main()`, so that you can use it there as well.

Comment: Does `struct _node` collide with C11 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
}node;

int main()  {
    int i;
    struct node *first=NULL;
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
        first=insertrear(first,i);
    dispnodes(first);
    sum(first);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Other things also need to be declared before main!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to modify:

1. you have to declare the the `struct` ,`typedef` and all the functions  you are calling before `main` function.Compiler should be provided with the declaration before it encounters any of them.
2. Also you haven't provided a label to the `typedef` to structure `node`,you can do  something like this:

   ```
   typedef struct node {
       int data;
       struct node *link;
   } Node ;
   ```

   or use `struct node` instead of `node` to declare a variable of `struct node` type

Here is the code after modification:

```
typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *link;
} Node ;

void dispnodes(Node *first);
node* insertrear(Node *first,int a);
void sum(Node *first);

int main()  {
    int i;
    struct node *first=NULL;
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
        first=insertrear(first,i);
    dispnodes(first);
    sum(first);

    return 0;
}
// rest of the code
```